# Get all fields of a document in ElasticSearch search query

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get all fields in documents matched by search query? ES documentation on `fields` says that using `*`, one can get all fields: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html

Having this document and this query, I get hit in result, but no fields are returned:

Put document:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/idx/t/doc1 -d '{
  "f": "value"
}'
```

Search it:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/idx/_search?pretty -d '{
  "fields": "*",
  "query": { "term" : { "f" : "value" }}
}'
```

I tried also `["*"]`, but the result is the same, only default fields (`_id` and `_type`) are returned. The hits part of response looks like this:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.30685282,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "idx",
      "_type" : "t",
      "_id" : "doc1",
      "_score" : 0.30685282
    } ]
  }
```

Comment: Your document has one field; you don't get it back?

Comment: @AlainCollins See updated text with response from ES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) actually says:

> "* can be used to load all stored fields from the document."

The [core types doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) says that the default for storing fields is 'false'.

> Since by default ElasticSearch stores all fields of the source document in the special _source field, this option is primarily useful when the _source field has been disabled in the type definition. Defaults to false.

If you don't specify 'fields' in your search, you can see what's in _source.

So, if you want to return it as a field, change your mapping to store the field.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing this problem, too.
I found out that if I just search the `text` or `keyword` fields, everything is OK. 
Hope this may help you.